# How to recover data from broken phone broken?

Tags: backup, nokia-lumia-535

My Lumia 535 is broken and I forgot my Microsoft account username and password. I have the IMEI number and MAC address - how can I get my all data off the phone?

Comment: Did you sent any mail from outlook to anyone? then you can collect your live mail id from them. May be you can recover your password from your username.

Comment: ok thaks i will think and try

Answer (score 1):

Some techies should be able to read the data from the phone's solid state drive.
Or you can try contacting Microsoft support for aid. They might be able to tell the email by IMEI.